D3DXSaveTextureToFileW doesn't working properly
It seems that the screenshot is not being generated properly after this code:
IDirect3DBaseTexture9* pBaseTexture = nullptr;
pDevice->GetTexture(0, &pBaseTexture);

if (pBaseTexture != NULL) {

    std::cout << "Saving screenshot..." << std::endl;

    const wchar_t* fileName = L"C:\\Screenshots\\pBaseTexture.png";
    D3DXSaveTextureToFileW(fileName, D3DXIFF_PNG, pBaseTexture, nullptr);
}

I'm trying to print an image using a d3d9 hook.

If you don't want use the D3DX9.
You can use stb_image_write.h instead.
D3DSURFACE_DESC desc;
pBackBuffer->GetDesc(&desc);

int width = desc.Width;
int height = desc.Height;

int bufferSize = width * height * 4;
unsigned char* imageData = new unsigned char[bufferSize];

D3DLOCKED_RECT lockedRect;
pBackBuffer->LockRect(&lockedRect, NULL, D3DLOCK_READONLY);

unsigned char* sourceData = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(lockedRect.pBits);
memcpy(imageData, sourceData, bufferSize);

int jpeg_quality = 90;
stbi_write_jpg(fullPath, width, height, 4, imageData, jpeg_quality);


I got it guys.
Just follow this code if anyone needs it.
void SaveD3D9Screenshot(IDirect3DDevice9* pDevice, const wchar_t* fileName) {

    IDirect3DSurface9* pBackBuffer = nullptr;

    if (SUCCEEDED(pDevice->GetBackBuffer(0, 0, D3DBACKBUFFER_TYPE_MONO, &pBackBuffer))) {

        std::cout << "[D3D9 HOOK] - Saving screenshot..." << std::endl;

        D3DXSaveSurfaceToFileW(fileName, D3DXIFF_PNG, pBackBuffer, nullptr, nullptr);
        pBackBuffer->Release();
    }
}


Please note D3DX9 is deprecated and has numerous issues. If you must continue to use it, see this post. A better option would be to use the code from GitHub. to write the file.
